# Does the value of RMSD have any impact on my vina results? Are results with RMSD greater than 2 unreliable?

Tags: proteins, docking

This is part of my result.I saw someone saying that Vina docking results with rmsd greater than 2 are unreliable, but I don’t know how to judge.Help,plz！
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please paste your text-based table as text into your question. Images are harder to read, reformat and interpret.